# Why "#include <string>" doesn't work on rosserial?

Tags: rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I work with ROS and Arduino and I want to include some libraries like `#include <string>` or `#include <vector>` to my rosserial program. When i compile, i have : `fatal error: string: No such file or directory #include <string>`.

I haven't find a solution. If someone can explain me how should i do.

Thank for your help.

William

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260101/why-%22#include-%3Cstring%3E%22-doesn%27t-work-on-rosserial?/) by [w.fradin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29616/w.fradin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Headers like `string` and `vector` are part of the STL, which isn't included with the Arduino IDE by default. See this discussion for more details:

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24790/is-the-c-stl-fully-supported-on-arduino

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2